# Getting Error while creating APP BUNDLE from android studio

Tags: android

File 'root/res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'
I have tried to exclude it in gradle file.

android.packagingOptions {
exclude 'values-sw600dp'
}

but no luck.